# ELPD and number of observations

Tags: regression, bayesian, goodness-of-fit, model-evaluation

Bit of a Bayesian noob here with a very simple question - does ELPD of a model depend on the number of observations / datapoints?

Longer version: I am comparing several models for the same underlying dataset, but grouped different ways such that the number of datapoints is different for different models.

I recently switched the back-end from simple default R linear regression (`lm`) to Bayesian regression (`brms`), and so have tried to switch model evaluation metrics as well.

Some metrics for evaluating model fit like RMSE, MAE, or MAPE, because they take the mean across all datapoints, are not directly sensitive to number of datapoints, right? so I can compare them directly across models slicing the data different ways with resulting different `n`. But I don't know (and am not smart enough to figure out) if you can do that with ELPD.

I am noticing in my results that ELPD differences are much greater between models on data sliced differently (hence different `n`) than between models with the same `n`. While it's plausible that those models genuinely fit much better, I want to make sure I'm not messing up the interpretation.